# Vfork system call

Tags: unix

In vfork system call, parent and child processes share the pages, any change in a global variable(let say) by the child process, will reflect to the parent process as well, once it returned. Now, if we execute the exec() system call from the child process, it will load the specified program into the address space of child process, when the parent process will become active again, wouldn't it finds out the corrupted data and stack frames(with the new binary loaded by child process) ?.
Please reply,

Answer (score 0):

No, the kernel arranges for this not to be a problem.  I don't remember the exact details anymore, but the general procedure is: When a process calls `vfork` the kernel saves the stack pointer and PC, and does part of the setup for a child process.  When a process that has called `vfork` calls `execve`, the kernel creates a new address space for the new program image, instead of overwriting the calling process's address space.  It then reverts the parent's stack pointer and PC to what they used to be, and the parent continues from the point of the `vfork`.

Online manpages for `vfork` are disappointingly vague and tend to have snarky comments about its danger and lack of utility, which is not fair -- it really is more efficient than `fork`, even with copy-on-write address space sharing, because it doesn't need to flush the TLB or do nearly as much work in the kernel, and its semantics are fairly consistent across OSes still in wide use.  Error handling is a pain in the ass, but error handling with plain `fork` is just as bad if you're serious about it.

[Does anyone know if it's safe to do I/O redirection setup in between `vfork` and `execve`?  The standard doesn't guarantee it, and the manpages don't either, but my recollection is that open/close/dup operations in that window affect the child-to-be only, like with `fork`.]

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph; I resisted the temptation to do -1 for the second paragraph.

Comment: I've definitely seen people do that and I've never heard of anyone having problems with it.  Case in point: http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/libiberty/pex-unix.c?revision=168438&view=markup